# How to get and set the selected value of a Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

All the answers on stack overflow show how this can be done with an on click event but i'm looking to get the selected value without triggering the on click event.

```
<div class="dropdown" >
  <button id="ddown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" >Select Value   
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul id="ulRating" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" target="_self" dropdown-val="3">Tres</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self" dropdown-val="2">Dos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self" dropdown-val="1">Unos</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also i'm using a hack to set the value currently. Is there a better way to do the set part?

```
$("#ulRating li a").filter("[dropdown-val=" + result.value + "]").trigger('click');
```